# Windows 10 - MEMORY_MANAGEMENT bsod on startup after installing linux dual boot

Tags: boot, windows-10, bsod, dell-latitude, memory-management

I recently installed a Kali linux dual boot on my laptop, and now every time i try to boot into windows, it crashes with a MEMORY_MANAGEMENT error before it even reaches the login screen.

I've already searched for solutions on the internet but they all involve tools that are part of windows itself, so I can't use them. I have also tried using a recovery drive and a windows install usb, but those also crashed with the same error before I was able to do anything.

I thought it was a RAM issue at first, but a BIOS RAM test found no errors and linux runs perfectly fine, so i'm pretty sure the installation screwed up my boot partition somehow.

My laptop is a Dell Latitude 7350

Comment: boot to Linux and run memtest86+

Comment: See if the Tools from [Here](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) can help you out. **Rescatux** may help you fix it if its a problem with booting it can help you repair grub and fix windows which may be the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I have dual boot on my pc and windows crashes if I reboot from ubuntu and choose windows 10 in grub. But it works fine if I shut down ubuntu completly and turn on computer again. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Does it crash with the same error message?